# OpenRasta: Prioritize requests or: make requests asynchronous

Tags: openrasta

Two years ago, there was a discussion on asynchronous request processing in OpenRasta:
http://groups.google.com/group/openrasta/browse_thread/thread/34a599e21bf65d53

Googleing 'openrasta' and 'async' doesn't yield much more than the above link, and a quick grep  through the source code (http://svn.caffeine-it.com/openrasta/trunk/src) did not look promising either.

So is it already possible to prioritize requests (so that IO-bound ones get queued, whereas quick ones will always be processed synchronously), using asp.net?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We've not built anything for it yet, it's technically very possible to do, and quite easily as we already support resumable pipeline. There's just not been enough requests for it to spend the engineering time.

Comment: I'd potentially be interested in implementing this, preferably in a way that you'd be happy to incorporate into OpenRasta once done. There's a couple of questions though, in addition to what you have on http://groups.google.com/group/openrasta/browse_thread/thread/34a599e21bf65d53 . I actually prefer option 1, if we extend that with e.g. a priority information in the [Async] attribute (in case we do it that way), otherwise, as you say, it'd be pointless. Option 2 would force a lot of boilerplate on the implementors of every single method. Anyway, where could we discuss all this?

Comment: The place to talk about dev of that kind of functionality is on the mailing list, pop an email there :)

Comment: Actually, for now it's good to know that it can be added in the future. As soon as our product is finished and once the need to add that feature develops, I'll implement it. But with the knowledge that it's possible, we now actually made the decision to go with OpenRasta, as 1) it is available (in contrast to Web API, which will take another 6 months at least) and it 2) seems to allow me to customize it to all my needs.

Comment: Glad you're liking it. Happy to help building async support in if it's not there by the time you require it.